# Change the output format used from a view export

Tags: views, 8

I have a REST EXPORT view with particular fields in Drupal 8. I want to remove the main array which is printing by default.
The response is coming like this.

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Product",
    "body": "<p>Here are the Product Details</p>"
  }
]
```

I expect the response to be like the following one.

```json
{
  "title": "Product",
  "body": "<p>Here are the Product Details</p>"
}
```